# osx - Why can't my text editor (Text Wrangler) find lxml but I can use it when running Python from Terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, lxml, text-editor, textwrangler

I'm trying to import lxml into my code that I'm working with in text editor, using:

```
from lxml import etree
```

But when I run my code, I get an import error that says

> No module named 'lxml'

If I run python from the terminal, however, I can use the lxml module with no problem. Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: How do you run your code from text wrangler? How do you execute your code in the terminal? Do you have virtual environments?

Comment: Probably TextWrangler is running a different `python` binary than you are running in the Terminal.  For some potential solutions, see [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/227224/textwrangler-running-python-2-7-after-i-removed-it-from-my-mac) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/textwrangler/JgNHoJ3uaUM).